# Formik field mapping and yup validation not working on sign in form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup, formik-material-ui

I am trying to create a simple sign in form using formik and material ui however when I enter data into the form the fields are still coming blank and validation is not working.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useFormik, Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Field from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const SignIn = () => {

    const validation = yup.object({
        email: yup
        .string()
        .email('Enter a valid email')
        .required('Email is required'),
        password: yup
        .string()
        .min(8, 'Password should be of minimum 8 characters length')
        .required('Password is required'),
    });

    
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{ email: "", password: ""}}
                validationSchema={validation}
                onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    setSubmitting(false);
                }}
            >
                <Form>
                    <Field id='email' name='email' label='Email' type='text' variant='outlined'></Field>
                    <Field id='password' label='Password' type='text' variant='outlined'></Field>
                    <Button className='submit' type='submit' variant='outlined'>Login</Button>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SignIn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, to ensure proper integration of *Yup* validations within Formik, it's crucial to bind the *onBlur* attribute alongside the field values. This binding enables Formik to track user interaction with the form fields, triggering validation checks as necessary. Without this setup, the validations specified using Yup won't be activated. Essentially, by associating the *onBlur* event handler with each field, Formik can accurately validate user input upon field interaction, providing a seamless and responsive form validation experience.

Below are a few code suggestions/changes. Hope this helps:p

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFormik, Formik, Form } from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'; // Changed Field to TextField

const SignIn = () => {
    const validation = yup.object({
        email: yup
        .string()
        .email('Enter a valid email')
        .required('Email is required'),
        password: yup
        .string()
        .min(8, 'Password should be of minimum 8 characters length')
        .required('Password is required'),
    });

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: { email: '', password: '' },
        validationSchema: validation,
        onSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            setSubmitting(false);
        },
    });
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Sign In</h2>
            <Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <TextField 
                    id='email' 
                    name='email' 
                    label='Email' 
                    type='text' 
                    variant='outlined' 
                    value={formik.values.email} 
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur} 
                    onChange={formik.handleChange} 
                />
                {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email ? (
                    <div>{formik.errors.email}</div>
                ) : null}
                <TextField 
                    id='password' 
                    name='password' 
                    label='Password' 
                    type='password' // Changed to password type for password field
                    variant='outlined' 
                    value={formik.values.password} 
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur} 
                    onChange={formik.handleChange} 
                />
                {formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password ? (
                    <div>{formik.errors.password}</div>
                ) : null}
                <Button className='submit' type='submit' variant='outlined'>Login</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SignIn;
```